# update only needed field mvc EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

My code is like this
Model

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; } //no appointments when false
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int CreatedUserId
    {
        get { return ((SystemUser) HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"]).SystemUserID; }
    }

}
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="DepartmentID,Name,CreatedUser,CreatedDate")] Department department)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(department).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(department);
    }
```

View (Edit)

```
    @model DiagnosisApp.Models.Department

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DepartmentID)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Department Name" })
        <button type="submit" value="Save" >Save</button>

}
```

As you can see in view I only want to Update the `Name` field , But when I run the code all fields in table are updated.For which columns I have not added value gets updated with null. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: its because you UI model dont have all the fields rendered. So for those properties which is not used in the UI model binding sending null values

Comment: Get the existing item from the database, update its `Name` based on the posted values and save the original. Note you can remove `CreatedUser, CreatedDate` from the `[Bind(Include...)]`

Comment: Is it a good practice to render unwanted fields in UI? Is there no other way to overcome this? May be inside Controller Logic?

Comment: No its not. I am posting an answer soon to update only one property

Comment: @StephenMuecke I haven't completely understood what you say. Can you please add it as an answer ?

Comment: @qamar Okay, thats great

Comment: No its not good practice. Its preferable to use a view model with only the properties you want to display/edit [refer What is a view model in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you have done wrong is forgot to attach the entity to the context. And of course model object don't have all the properties. So its model binder sending default values for those properties which is not rendered in the UI.

```
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Department.Attach(department);
                db.Entry(department).Property(x => x.name).IsModified = true;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

Comment: What you meant by [Your Entity Name]. I have posted my complete code in the question. Can you please point out what I need to replace it with?

Comment: Updated answer please take a look

Comment: Please mark it answer then so that community gets help :)